# Comparing NSArray values with NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios6, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have an `NSMutableDictionary` which was created from a JSON string.

The problem is that I need to do some pretty complex data comparisons between a `NSArray` and a `NSMutableDictionary`. I cannot figure out an efficient way to do so.

The dictionary looks like this:

`dictionaryMain`

```
0 = {
    key1 = value1;
    key2 = value2;
    key3 = {
        subKey1 = {
            subSubKey1 = {
                inner1 = apples;
                inner2 = oranges;
            };
            subSubKey2 = {
                inner1 = grapes;
                inner2 = lemons;
            };
            subSubKey3 = {
                inner1 = mangoes;
                inner2 = kiwis;
            };
        };
    };
    key4 = {
        subKey1 = {
            subSubKey1 = {
                inner1 = pineapples;
                inner2 = apples;
            };
            subSubKey2 = {
                inner1 = oranges;
                inner2 = mangoes;
            };
        };
    };
};

1 = {
    key1 = value1;
    key2 = value2;
    key3 = {
        subKey1 = {
            subSubKey1 = {
                inner1 = watermelon;
                inner2 = grapes;
            };
            subSubKey7 = {
                inner1 = bananas;
                inner2 = oranges;
            };
        };
    };
    key4 = {
        subKey1 = {
            subSubKey5 = {
                inner1 = kiwis;
                inner2 = mangoes;
            };
        };
    };
};

// ... and so on
```

I have an array `arrayOfKeys` which has some of the `subSubKey`s as follows:

`arrayOfKeys`

```
{
    subSubKey5,
    subSubKey7,
    subSubKey10
}
```

I need to loop through my `NSMutableDictionary` and select only those objects that have the same keys as defined by `arrayOfKeys`. These selected objects will be added to a new dictionary.

For example, if `arrayOfKeys` contains `subSubKey7`, then the *object [1]* will be selected from the `NSMutableDictionary` since a key deep inside it has the name `subSubKey7`.

I tried to figure out a simple way to do this but I couldn't come up with a viable solution. The only thing that I can think of doing is using a lot of nested loops and dirty quick code.

I spent two days trying to figure this out. Any solution for this problem, guys?

Thanks!

Comment: if you could restructure the json to include object 1 as a value for subkey7, or as suggested below some function that states if subkey = x, return object, else call function again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a recursive method (or function) which checks the dictionary it is passed and calls itself to process any sub dictionaries. The method should return anything it finds and anything found when it calls itself.

If there should only be one result array (from one level) the method could return as soon as it is found or as soon as the result of calling itself is non-nil.

Comment: Are you introducing the term "recursive" for the OP or assuming that the OP knows what it means?